# index match return NA value

Tags: vba

I have a vba code that find the value at the intersection of columns and rows.
It works well with all my data except for one : it returns NA.
The value i want to return is the same as usual, it just doesn't work with this intersection.
Can you help me figure out why?
Thank you

```
With Perftitres
Set VMt = Data1.Range("U:U")
Set Ticker = Data1.Range("H:H")
End With

    ' Calculs de perf
   For Each sht In Perftitres.Worksheets
    If sht.Visible = True Then
            If sht.Cells(1, 1) = "" Then
            sht.Cells(1, 1) = "Date"
            sht.Cells(1, 2) = "Code du placement"
            sht.Cells(1, 3) = "Valeur marchande t"
            sht.Cells(1, 4) = "Valeur marchande t-1"
            sht.Cells(1, 5) = "Valeur des achats"
            sht.Cells(1, 6) = "Valeur des ventes"
            sht.Cells(1, 7) = "Facteur"
            sht.Cells(1, 8) = "Rendement 1 mois"
            End If
    LastRowsht = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    LastColumnsht = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
    sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 1) = 20 & Left(Dateupdate, 2) & "-" &   Right(Dateupdate, 2)
    sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2) = sht.Name
    sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 3) = Application.Index(VMt, Application.Match(sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2), Ticker))
End If
Next sht

Data1.Visible = True
Data2.Visible = True
```

This line doesn't work as expected for only one sheet. For every other one it works.

```
   sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 3) = Application.Index(VMt, Application.Match(sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2), Ticker))
```

Comment: To state the obvious - are you sure the data matches for this sheet? Have you tried hardcoding in values that you know will match, to see what happens? Going deeper, have you attempted to debug (using the STOP method and pressing f8 line by line), hovering over the values in the code, to see what they are assigned as, vs what you would expect?

Comment: It works for the first 2 pages.
After this, it finds the wrong value or NA.
I tried debug mode but the mistake seems to be on this line.

Comment: And are all of the pages identical? Not just in terms of how the values look visually, but in how Excel interprets them? ie: " " <> "".

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer :

```
    sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 3) = Application.Index(VMt,    Application.Match(sht.Cells(LastRowsht + 1, 2), Ticker,0),0)
```

I had to had 0 and 0 for exact matches